# How can I retrieve the machine name from a remote Windows computer?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, computer-name

I am trying to find a way to retrieve Computer name from an IP address in C#, but all of the answers marked online as retrieving machine name or computer name *actually* get the hostname, not the Computer Name.  If you go to Control panel > system, there is a property in that menu "Computer name" ... I'm looking for this value on a remote machine.  AFAIK, the HOSTNAME will = the *full* computer name IF there is no DNS mapping.  The problem is that these servers I'm working on do have DNS mapping so the hostname returns their DNS address.

Feel free to correct me on the technical details of that if I said anything wrong, but the question will remain.

I've tried this:

```
IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(_ip);

_hostname = hostEntry.HostName;
```

but obviously returns the HostName, not the Computer name. I could also settle for the "Full computer name" property being returned, and then simply strip the unneeded parts of the string off to reveal the "Computer name."

Also, if you know how to do this with PowerShell, I could use your help as-well.  I am hosting the PowerShell engine in my app anyway... so could simply pass your command into `PowerShellInstance.AddScript(_yourCommandHere);` and pipe its return back into my app.

Please advise if this is possible to do.

@DanielAWhite
EDIT: How is this a duplicate of the listed answer?  The answer in that post says exactly what I posted as being the *problem* to this question.  No, that's not a duplicate, because I'm NOT looking for the hostname.  I specifically told you in my OP that I *wasn't* looking for that, and they're not asking what I'm asking.  If there is no way to get the computer name from the IP in .NET then just answer the question with that.

From the "duplicate":

> Well, not every IP address has a name. However, given the IPAddress you can use >Dns.GetHostEntry to try to resolve it. Also note that if it's being a NAT >router, you'll be getting the router's IP address rather than their actual >machine.

look at my OP... .GetHostEntry DOESN'T work.  that's the whole reason I took the time to type this up.

thanks

DOUBLE EDIT: BACON has an answer for how to do this; this post was locked because someone didn't take the time to actually read what I wrote.  Since it's locked, you also can't give a better answer.  But here's how I did it, saving this here for future reference:

```
        //declare a string to be our machinename
        string machineName;
        //declare a string which we will pass into powershell later as script
        //assigns the hostname or IP
        string getComputer = "$ip = " + "\"" + ip + "\"" + "\r\n";
        //add to the string this, which gets the Win32_ComputerSystem.. @BACON knew what I was after
        //we pipe that back using |select -expand Name
        getComputer += "get-wmiobject -class Win32_ComputerSystem -property Name -ComputerName " + "$ip " +
            "|select -expand Name";
        //create a powershell instance using
        using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            //add the script into our instance of ps
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript(getComputer);
            //instantiate a collection to house our output from PS
            //you could also probably just instantiate a PSObject instead of a collection.. but this might be useful if modified to get an array of computer names... and this is how I did it so can't verify
            Collection<PSObject> psOutput;
            //assign psOutput from .Invoke() method
            psOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

            //you could trim this loop and get rid of it for only one IP
            foreach (var item in psOutput)
            {
               //machineName = MachineName||ComputerName string NOT hostname
                machineName = item.BaseObject.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Oh, and per bacon in the comments, you have to have WMI allowed through windows firewall for this to work.  It worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174834/how-do-i-get-the-netbios-name-of-a-machine-from-ip-in-c) go in the right direction?

Comment: I think having "from IP address" in the title (instead of "of a remote machine") and the code snippet with `System.Net` classes would make this look like a duplicate to someone skimming quickly.  To clarify, you're looking to get the machine name - that is, the name the operating system uses to identify its own computer - and not necessarily (or absolutely not) related to DNS, right?  DNS may only be involved as far as _connecting_ to the remote computer but you don't want the name _according_ to DNS, yes?  Is this a Windows-only environment?  Does Active Directory come into play?

Comment: Off the top of my head, there's the `%COMPUTERNAME%`/`$Env:COMPUTERNAME` environment variable, .NET has the [`Environment.MachineName` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.environment.machinename), and then whatever registry value ultimately stores the text those return.  Even better would be the `Name` property of the singleton [`Win32_ComputerSystem` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem), which should be even easier to query remotely.  (Note that same class provides a `DNSHostName` property as well.)

Comment: @BACON nice... yeah the Environment.MachineName is exactly what I'm looking for.  So you're thinking run a query against an IP address, and then return the Win32_ComputerSystem Name property?  Appreciate the help sir

Comment: You could connect to the remote machine by IP or even by DNS name and the results would be the same since the machine itself - not DNS - stores the value.  With PowerShell you could easily query the remote value of `[Environment]::MachineName` or `$Env:COMPUTERNAME` using `Invoke-Command`; reading those remotely using C#/.NET would not be so easy.  I think WMI would be the most efficient way, though, and that would also work equally well from PowerShell or C#, too.  That'd be `Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $nameOrIp -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property Name` in PowerShell or 4-6 lines in C#.

Comment: No you can't put an IP into computername.  That doesn't work.

https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/9c7s3u/ip_address_for_computername/

yeah if I could some combination of invoke-command [Environment]::MachineName would work

Comment: For what cmdlet? I was just speaking generally that for any of the mentioned queries, if successful, the value won't change based on whether you address the remote computer by name or by IP. That Reddit question is about an unrelated cmdlet (`Get-Process`), anyways.  `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $nameOrIp -ScriptBlock { [Environment]::MachineName }` and `Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $nameOrIp -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property Name` both work on my non-domain Windows 10 network as long as the value of `$nameOrIp` (whether a name or IP) is added to `WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts`.

Comment: @bacon interesting... but the only way that would be useful is if I add a list of every single IP possible to TrustedHosts.  I guess I could do that.  I'll try it tomorrow and see if it works. ty

Comment: I tested and found that `TrustedHosts` accepts wildcards but not subnet masks or CIDR notation.  `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property Name -ComputerName $nameOrIp` works as well without needing to add the value of `$nameOrIp` to `TrustedHosts`, though it did require enabling the `Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI-In)` rule in Windows Firewall.

Answer (score 4):

*Reconstituting my comments as an answer...*

Imagine we had an `interface` like this...

```cs
namespace SO56585341
{
    public interface IComputerInfoSource
    {
        string GetComputerName();
    }
}
```

There are a handful of ways to implement this to get the machine name of the **local computer**.  The simplest is to return the value of the [`Environment.MachineName` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.environment.machinename)...

```cs
namespace SO56585341
{
    public class EnvironmentClassComputerInfoSource : IComputerInfoSource
    {
        public string GetComputerName()
        {
            return System.Environment.MachineName;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use the [`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable#System_Environment_GetEnvironmentVariable_System_String_) to retrieve the value of the `%ComputerName%` environment variable...

```cs
namespace SO56585341
{
    public class EnvironmentVariableComputerInfoSource : IComputerInfoSource
    {
        public string GetComputerName()
        {
            return System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ComputerName");
        }
    }
}
```

You can [p/invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke) the [`GetComputerName()` Windows API function](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcomputernamew), which is what `Environment.MachineName` does [behind the scenes](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs,be0b5c103d248dce)...

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace SO56585341
{
    public class WinApiComputerInfoSource : IComputerInfoSource
    {
        private const int MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH = 15;

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool GetComputerName(
            StringBuilder lpBuffer,
            ref int nSize
        );

        public string GetComputerName()
        {
            int maxCapacity = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
            StringBuilder nameBuilder = new StringBuilder(maxCapacity, maxCapacity);

            if (!GetComputerName(nameBuilder, ref maxCapacity))
            {
                // TODO: Error handling...
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
            }

            return nameBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

You can use WMI to retrieve the `Name` property of the singleton [`Win32_ComputerSystem` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem).  You can do this by instantiating a [`ManagementClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.managementclass) instance for the `Win32_ComputerSystem` class and calling [`GetInstances()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.managementclass.getinstances) on it to retrieve an array containing the sole instance...

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;

namespace SO56585341
{
    public class WmiClassComputerInfoSource : IComputerInfoSource
    {
        public string GetComputerName()
        {
            using (ManagementClass computerSystemClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystem"))
            using (ManagementObjectCollection computerSystemCollection = computerSystemClass.GetInstances())
            using (ManagementObject computerSystem = computerSystemCollection.Cast<ManagementObject>().Single())
                return (string) computerSystem["Name"];
        }
    }
}
```

...or by creating a [`ManagementObjectSearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher) and using that to [`Get()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.get) the lone `Win32_ComputerSystem` instance...

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;

namespace SO56585341
{
    public class WmiSearcherComputerInfoSource : IComputerInfoSource
    {
        public string GetComputerName()
        {
            ObjectQuery computerSystemQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_ComputerSystem");

            using (ManagementObjectSearcher computerSystemSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(computerSystemQuery))
            using (ManagementObjectCollection computerSystemCollection = computerSystemSearcher.Get())
            using (ManagementObject computerSystem = computerSystemCollection.Cast<ManagementObject>().Single())
                return (string) computerSystem["Name"];
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the value returned by all of the methods above seems to ultimately be stored in the registry, so if you don't mind relying on that implementation detail you can retrieve it from there directly...

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace SO56585341
{
    public class RegistryComputerInfoSource : IComputerInfoSource
    {
        public string GetComputerName()
        {
            // See also @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName\"
            // https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/windows-nt-workstation/9781565926134/10_chapter-07.html
            const string valueParentKeyPath = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName\";

            using (RegistryKey parentKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(valueParentKeyPath, false))
                return (string) parentKey.GetValue("ComputerName");
        }
    }
}
```

---

As for getting the same value from a **remote computer** only the last three implementations above will work, though with minimal tweaking required.  First, just to complete this `IComputerInfoSource` example, let's create an `abstract` class to hold the remote machine name/address "parameter"...

```cs
namespace SO56585341
{
    public abstract class RemoteComputerInfoSource : IComputerInfoSource
    {
        public string RemoteNameOrIp
        {
            get;
        }

        protected RemoteComputerInfoSource(string nameOrIp)
        {
            RemoteNameOrIp = nameOrIp ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(nameOrIp));  
        }

        public abstract string GetComputerName();
    }
}
```

Retrieving the `Win32_ComputerSystem` instance via a `ManagementClass` just becomes a matter of explicitly passing it a [`ManagementPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.managementpath) that also specifies the [`NamespacePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.managementpath.namespacepath) and [`Server`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.managementpath.server)...

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;

namespace SO56585341
{
    public class RemoteWmiClassComputerInfoSource : RemoteComputerInfoSource
    {
        public RemoteWmiClassComputerInfoSource(string nameOrIp)
            : base(nameOrIp)
        {
        }

        public override string GetComputerName()
        {
            ManagementPath computerSystemPath = new ManagementPath() {
                ClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem",
                NamespacePath = @"root\cimv2",
                Server = RemoteNameOrIp
            };

            using (ManagementClass computerSystemClass = new ManagementClass(computerSystemPath))
            using (ManagementObjectCollection computerSystemCollection = computerSystemClass.GetInstances())
            using (ManagementObject computerSystem = computerSystemCollection.Cast<ManagementObject>().Single())
                return (string) computerSystem["Name"];
        }
    }
}
```

A `ManagementObjectSearcher` can be used by passing a similar `ManagementPath` wrapped in a [`ManagementScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.managementscope)...

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;

namespace SO56585341
{
    public class RemoteWmiSearcherComputerInfoSource : RemoteComputerInfoSource
    {
        public RemoteWmiSearcherComputerInfoSource(string nameOrIp)
            : base(nameOrIp)
        {
        }

        public override string GetComputerName()
        {
            ManagementScope computerSystemScope = new ManagementScope(
                new ManagementPath() {
                    NamespacePath = @"root\cimv2",
                    Server = RemoteNameOrIp
                }
            );
            ObjectQuery computerSystemQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_ComputerSystem");

            using (ManagementObjectSearcher computerSystemSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(computerSystemScope, computerSystemQuery))
            using (ManagementObjectCollection computerSystemCollection = computerSystemSearcher.Get())
            using (ManagementObject computerSystem = computerSystemCollection.Cast<ManagementObject>().Single())
                return (string) computerSystem["Name"];
        }
    }
}
```

Querying a remote registry just requires an additional call to [`OpenRemoteBaseKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openremotebasekey) to get a handle to the root of the remote hive...

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace SO56585341
{
    public class RemoteRegistryComputerInfoSource : RemoteComputerInfoSource
    {
        public RemoteRegistryComputerInfoSource(string nameOrIp)
        : base(nameOrIp)
        {
        }

        public override string GetComputerName()
        {
            // See also @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName\"
            // https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/windows-nt-workstation/9781565926134/10_chapter-07.html
            const string valueParentKeyPath = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName\";

            using (RegistryKey baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RemoteNameOrIp))
            using (RegistryKey parentKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey(valueParentKeyPath, false))
                return (string) parentKey.GetValue("ComputerName");
        }
    }
}
```

If you compile all of the above code into a project you can use the following `Program` class to test it...

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SO56585341
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private const string TestHost = "127.0.0.1";

        public static void Main()
        {
            // Get all non-abstract classes in the executing assembly that implement IComputerInfoSource
            IEnumerable<Type> computerInfoSourceTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                .Where(type => type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract && typeof(IComputerInfoSource).IsAssignableFrom(type));

            // For each constructor in each candidate class...
            foreach (Type computerInfoSourceType in computerInfoSourceTypes)
                foreach (ConstructorInfo constructor in computerInfoSourceType.GetConstructors())
                {
                    ParameterInfo[] constructorParameters = constructor.GetParameters();
                    object[] instanceParameters;

                    // If the constructor takes no parameters...
                    if (!constructorParameters.Any())
                        instanceParameters = Array.Empty<object>();
                    // ...or a single string parameter...
                    else if (constructorParameters.Length == 1 && constructorParameters[0].ParameterType == typeof(string))
                        instanceParameters = new object[1] { TestHost };
                    // ...otherwise skip this constructor
                    else
                        continue;

                    // Instantiate the class using the constructor parameters specified above
                    IComputerInfoSource computerInfoSource = (IComputerInfoSource) constructor.Invoke(instanceParameters);
                    string result;

                    try
                    {
                        result = computerInfoSource.GetComputerName();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        result = ex.ToString();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "new {0}({1}).{2}(): \"{3}\"",
                        computerInfoSourceType.Name,
                        string.Join(
                            ", ",
                            instanceParameters.Select(value => $"\"{value}\"")
                        ),
                        nameof(IComputerInfoSource.GetComputerName),
                        result
                    );
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I found this code to work whether `TestHost` was set to a machine name, CNAME, or IP address.  Note that the `Remote*ComputerInfoSource` classes will fail if...

- The appropriate service (`RemoteRegistry` or `Winmgmt`) is not running on the remote machine, or...
- The appropriate firewall rule (e.g. `WMI-WINMGMT-In-TCP`) is not enabled on the remote machine, or...
- The code is not run as a user with privileges to access the remote service.

---

As for PowerShell, one should be able to port the code of **any** of the above methods from C# (either a direct translation or using PowerShell's conveniences) and wrap them in a call to [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) since that code will be executed local to the remote machine.  For example...

```bsh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $nameOrIp -ScriptBlock { $Env:COMPUTERNAME }
```

...or...

```bsh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $nameOrIp -ScriptBlock {
    # See also 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName\'
    # https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/windows-nt-workstation/9781565926134/10_chapter-07.html
    Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName\' -Name 'ComputerName'
}
```

PowerShell also has the [`Get-WmiObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject)...

```bsh
Get-WmiObject   -Class 'Win32_ComputerSystem' -ComputerName $nameOrIp -Property 'Name'
```

...and [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) cmdlets...

```bsh
Get-CimInstance -Class 'Win32_ComputerSystem' -ComputerName $nameOrIp -Property 'Name'
```

...that make working with WMI much easier.  In general, **I would recommend using WMI** since it is pretty easy to use from C# and PowerShell for both local and remote queries, and it exists for exactly this purpose of retrieving system details without having to know about the underlying API calls or data representation.

Note that when using the `Invoke-Command` or `Get-CimInstance` cmdlets that the `WinRM` service must be running on the remote machine and the appropriate firewall rule (e.g. `WINRM-HTTP-In-TCP-NoScope`) must be enabled.  Also, when passing an IP address to the `-ComputerName` parameter of either of those cmdlets that address must be matched by the value of [`WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.wsman.management/about/about_wsman_provider).  If you need to scan an entire network by IP address I tested and found that `TrustedHosts` accepts the `*` wildcard but not subnet masks, CIDR notation, or the `?` wildcard.