# How to get the vendor OUI and Device name from MAC Address in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, networking

I am developing a network scanner in C++ with the help of libtins library, I can be able to get MAC addresses and IP but I want to go further to know the vendor(eg: Intel Corporate) and Device Name (eg: DESKTOP-TO5P0BD) in C++

---

codes to get Mac and IP

// Retrieve the ARP layer info

```
const ARP& arp = pdu.rfind_pdu<ARP>();
std::cout << "Found :" << arp.sender_ip_addr() << ", " << arp.sender_hw_addr() << std::endl;
// Checking if it is an ARP reply?
if (arp.opcode() == ARP::REPLY) {
    // Let's check if there's already an entry for this address
auto iter = addresses.find(arp.sender_ip_addr());
if (iter == addresses.end()) {
    std::cout << "saving " << arp.sender_ip_addr() << ", " << arp.sender_hw_addr() << std::endl;
    // We haven't seen this address. Save it.
    addresses.insert({ arp.sender_ip_addr(), arp.sender_hw_addr() });
    IPv4Address ip = arp.sender_ip_addr();
    NetworkInterface iface(ip);
    //std::cout << iface.name() << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "already seen " << arp.sender_ip_addr() << ", " << arp.sender_hw_addr() << std::endl;
    // We've seen this address. If it's not the same HW address, inform it
    if (arp.sender_hw_addr() != iter->second) {
        std::cout << "[WARNING] " << arp.sender_ip_addr() << " is at "
            << iter->second << " but also at " << arp.sender_hw_addr()
            << std::endl;
    }
}
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the vendor from the MAC address, you can have a look at [this MAC OUI vendor database](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/raw/master/manuf) mantained by Wireshark. It's a text file with a simple format.

In order to get the "device name", you can do a [NetBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS) name lookup. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174834/how-do-i-get-the-netbios-name-of-a-machine-from-ip-in-c) may help you.

Comment: The problem is, Can't be able to accomplish the MAC vendor's issue without going through its database? if No, No problem I can go for your answer but also the problem of Device name is still not answered, Please help

Comment: The Wireshark database is easy to parse with C/C++ and it's one of the best databases of MAC vendors (and it's actively maintained), so I don't see any problem for your program to get the MAC vendor from this database. About getting the device name, you can make a NetBIOS name lookup using UDP (this will work with most Windows computers). The fastest solution, however, could be to exec a command line utility from your program (on Windows you have [`nbtstat`](https://www.computerhope.com/nbtstat.htm)) and parse the stdout of the command.

Answer (score -1):

If you'd like the Vendor Name from the MAC, you could get the MAC by reading arp -a ([probably via the winapi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getipnettable)). Next you need to search a vendor db, the [wireshark list](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/raw/master/manuf) is good, there's also [this one](https://macaddress.io/database-download). As for the "Device Name", you could check this with WMI. Other than the [more complex winapi for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-a-remote-computer), you could use a library like [this one](https://github.com/Thomas-Sparber/wmi), which is much simpler. You'd need to make a request to the Win32_ComputerSystem class, which contains the Device Name and model number, among other things. MAC addresses can also be  retrieved by WMI, instead make the query to Win32_NetworkAdapter - it gives all of the interfaces so be sure to find the right one!

Comment: Excellent answer, I managed to get the Vendors database as JSON and loops unto it but I am still failing to get the device name (all the researches I have done, I have seen that I have to go to layer 7 Yet I only want to manipulate datagrams and Dataframes (Layer 2 and Layer 3)